# Extra padding on Chrome/Safari/Webkit -- any ideas?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, padding

My page has this extra padding on the top of page that I'm unable to remove. Tried everything under the sun and hope someone can show me the way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see a bit of extra padding not on the top but on the sides, in both Chrome and Safari, although it's a bit more pronounced in Chrome.

Comment: always use css reset to minimize differences accross browser

Comment: question is useless without code sample, used to contain a link but this is removed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your page has an element near the top with a top-margin that extends outside your page wrapper. If you have this:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0">
  <div class="section" style="margin: 40px 0"> Stuff! </div>
</div>
```

Then the `.section` element will be positioned at the top of the `.wrapper` and its 40px margin will extend out the top. This has to do with the way margins collapse together so that two margins between elements don't accumulate. You can prevent this by adding `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper.

In your markup, it's the `.mini-search` element that has a 40px top margin. Either remove this margin, or add `overflow: hidden` on the fieldset that contains it.

Comment: HOORAY -- andrew you nailed it! took off that goddam margin from .mini-search and repositioned it via padding now i'm good to go. thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 14):

The WebKit styles sheet contains the following:
'margin' and 'padding' properties:

```
-webkit-margin-before:
-webkit-margin-end:
-webkit-margin-after:
-webkit-margin-start:

-webkit-padding-before:
-webkit-padding-end:
-webkit-padding-after:
-webkit-padding-start:
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 4):

Use this css code:

```
/*Reset Safari User Agent Styles*/
* {-webkit-padding-start: 0px;}
```

The issue you comment is because the user agent style, I learn about it inspecting the body tag with the browser tool. You should track down the element styles on a navigator using the tools it provides (now all the importants include a DOM inspector) so you can demystify the non-standard behavior.

I know you dont ask for it but talking about WebKit stuffs, i paste a code for getting
rounded borders on every browser but IE.

```
.rounded
{
-moz-border-radius:5px; /*works on Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius:5px; /*works on Safari and Google Chrome*/
border-bottom-radius: 5px; /*works on Opera*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i trust you have done:

```
body {padding :0; margin:0}
```

by default the body tag has padding.

Comment: adding this line to my css made no difference - thx for the comment walter

Answer (score 1):

**It is**, in my opinion, caused by **an EMBED element added by some plugin just after the HTML opening tag*** (check "right click > inspect element" to see if it is really there). If yes, there are basically two options to follow:

1. **disable/remove the plugin** which is **responsible for adding the element**; (preferred, as it's global)
2. insert `embed{display:none}` into your style sheet.

---

*This was my case - the plugin called *default plugin* and both disabling & removing helped solve the issue.

Comment: Unconstructive comment: you **sure** do **love** using **bold**. =)

Comment: Um, I just wanted to point out the most important information so that those who don't feel like reading it all could get the point. :))

Comment: That's alright, you'll eventually learn (at least I came to this conclusion) that you're posting to help others, not to attract attention to your answer. Those who need help *will* read your whole post. On the other hand, if you're posting a question, then it may help to highlight the **most important parts**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fix it by removing the rule:

```
* { padding: 0 }
```

From your CSS. I'm not sure what that's breaking, but that is the cause.

Comment: I can confirm that this works, but I also have no idea why.  Using Chrome's built-in DOM viewer, you can see that the entire <body> tag seems to be shifted down, not just the header.  Very strange.

Comment: So what I'd recommend here is just using Eric Meyer's CSS Reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/ instead of "* {margin:0; padding:0}". HTH

Comment: thx eric - i noticed that too, but couldn't get to fixing it via css -- but andrew found the offending line and now i'm good -- thx for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Always include the YUI reset css file.

and: 
`body, html {padding: 0; margin:0}`  that's it!

Comment: omar, this one also did not work -- added the line you recommend but no change - thx though

Answer (score 0):

This works with IE (at least IE v10 in my tests):

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

The bottom one is the one that works for IE 10, just keeps all the dimensions to what you set a selector/element to be in the width and/or height.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my nav that has a padding and contains buttons. `Overflow:hidden` did work, but it also cut the buttons off, because they had a padding that crossed the border of the navs height. So I tried `overflow:visible` and that worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround for solving this issue on Chrome iOS. In simple terms, my approach to extending the web page past the iPhone notch is to zoom on the page, and scroll to the middle.

My full details and code can be found onmy github https://github.com/anthonypena97/chromeios-viewportfitcover

[image]