# CSS - why doesn't -webkit-padding disappear after list-style-type: none;?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering about this CSS command, what does it mean, where does it come from? I think it is from the list-style-type. But doesn't it disappear, when I turn list-style it off?

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
</ul>

-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

CSS

```
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795888/extra-padding-on-chrome-safari-webkit-any-ideas

Comment: counter part for other browsers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549591/webkit-padding-start-40px-what-it-should-be-for-ie-and-firefox

Comment: you mean => **why doesn't -webkit-padding-start: 40px; disappear?** ???

Comment: @NoobEditor yes, after list-style-type: none; it should disappear or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ul elemten has be default a padding and a margin. You simply have to set:

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

Answer (score 1):

From [CSS Infos](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-padding-start):

> Provides the width of the starting padding.
>
> If the writing direction is left-to-right, this value overrides
>   `padding-left`. If the writing direction is right-to-left, this value
>   overrides `padding-right`.

If you wish to turn off padding on a `<ul>` or `<ol>` list, you'll need to use:

```
ul, ol {
    padding: 0
}
```

Comment: I think it is from the list-style-type. But doesn't it disapear, when I turn it off?

Comment: Yes, setting the value to `0` will turn it off? See the updated answer.